# Concerning as a verb?

Tags: verbing

During a conversation, I said "I am not concerning", instead of opting for " I am not concerned".

I figured it would be alright as "I am not hurting" instead of "I am not hurt" is perfectly fine (AFAIK).

How correct is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*to hurt* can be transitive or intransitive.

*to concern* is always transitive.

So your answer was incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

But it would be OK to say "I am not concerning *myself* with such matters at the moment".  It carries more of a sense of 'bothering', or 'getting involved, as opposed to your presumed intent of 'caring''.